# Can someone tell me what does "XThrowIfError" does?

Tags: iphone

I cannot find its definition in the documentation...

Answer (score 7):

This is a macro defined in Apple's iPublicUtility classes, included with several of their sample code packages, such as SpeakHere. Specifically, it's in the header CAXException.h.

Given a call `XThrowIfError(error, operation)`, it essentially throws a `CAXException()` if `error` is non-zero.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a search and from it's usage in the code on [this page](http://lists.apple.com/archives/coreaudio-api/2006/Jan/msg00076.html) on Apple's mailing list archive I'd say that it calls the method you supply as the first argument and throws an exception if it returns an error.

However, this is just a guess.